# Find characters that appear in all strings of a list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm a typical hello-world and I'm trying to write a function that iterates through a list of strings and compares substrings (letters in my case).As output I would like to receive "symbol which found in every string" . Till now I arrived to:

```
internal_input = ["hello", "world", "python", ]


def in_all_str(x):
    result = ""
    for _i in x:
        for _j in _i:
            if _j in x[0] and _j in x[1] and _j in x[2]:
                result = {_j}
    return result


print(in_all_str(internal_input))
```

output:
{'o'}

but I would like to make this func independent from list's length

Comment: Please provide sample input & desired output. That will help to clarify your issue

Answer (score 5):

You can use [set.intersection()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) for that:

```
x = ["hello", "world", "python"]

result = set.intersection(*map(set, x))   # {'o'}
```

As pointed out in the comments, this will not work for an empty list. If that is required a check needs to be added:

```
x = []

result = set.intersection(*map(set, x)) if x else set()   # set()
```

Comment: FWIW this is one of the few situations where using `map` is probably better than a comprehension as there's already a callback (native too) (`set.intersection(*map(set, x))`)

Comment: Works for *almost* all list lengths.

Comment: @Masklinn: I like that suggestion. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: Haha, good spot! I have updated my answer.

Comment: I guess the "theoretical" reason it doesn't work is that the intersection of the empty set is *not* really the empty set but the set of "everything", and the function can't possibly return that. Rather disappointing that `set.union()`, which *could* correctly return an empty set, doesn't work either. I'm considering filing a bug report :-)

Comment: Ah, [someone already did](https://bugs.python.org/issue35338).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: And it was closed... Interesting read though.